# AWS Cognito HTTP authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I try to set up a test API with AWS API Gateway, Lambda and Cognito so secure the access. Since I am new to the AWS world, I am not sure how can I create a "logged in" post request to the AWS service with for example the [request library](https://github.com/request/request) 
I guess on the client side I first have to log in via Cognito and the AWS Api and then use the informations I get to create a signed request like it is described here:http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html ?

If I am on the wrong path, please tell me and point me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preface:
I will explain the flow of Google+ integration with Cognito, it goes almost the same for others. I will use node.js (javascript), after that you can have your users authenticated from Google and authorized by IAM and Cognito to access API Gateway.

Cognito is a federated login service, it offers you to sync "configuration" of your mobile/web app. First you have to setup cognito with an identity provider, say Google+ for example. for that:

1. Create a Google app in your Developer console
2. Create a pool in cognito and add google as a provider, configure your pool with the policies and the roles (services you want to give your users access to, in this case only API Gateway).
3. In your web/mobile app, show the user Google+ Signin button, after the user clicks on it, google will call back a callback url with code parameter `code`, use that token
4. Use this code to get a Cognito identity for your user, in this case We trust Google:

> ```
> var params = {
>   IdentityPoolId: setting.POOL_ID,
>   Logins: {
>     'accounts.google.com': google_token  // Coming from Google OAuth2
>   }
> }
>
> // Get Id from Cognito
> cognitoIdentity.getId(params, resolverFunction);
> ```

5. Get IAM temporary credentials forthat Identity `IdentityId`, your Google authenticated user:

> ```
> var params = {
>   IdentityId: IdentityId,
>   Logins: {
>     'accounts.google.com': google_token // Coming from Google OAuth2
>   }
> }
> cognitoIdentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(params, resolverFunction)
> ```

6. Your user is now authenticated with Google and have the authorization from the IAM service (through the roles/policies you attached to your Cognito pool).
7. In your API Gateway, activate the IAM authorization, and use the Credentials you got from point 7.
8. Use the Accesskey, secretKey and the token to sign every request you make for your API built on top of API Gateway, you can you use this lib: [aws-v4-sign-small](https://github.com/nisaacson/aws-v4-sign-small)

Quick notes and headsup:

- All of this is Asynchronous actions, so If you are in node js, it is way better to use Promises (ES6 or Bluebird).
- Pay super attention to the roles you attached (acces to dynamodb document or S3 file, etc. read more about IAM it is suer helpful and you can do a fine grained authorizations)

Hope it is clear or at least it gives you a direction to start with.

Comment: Thank you very much: I tried it like this: [code]var ci = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({region: 'us-east-1'});
    var params = {
      AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: false,
      IdentityPoolName: 'xxxx',
      Logins: {
        'graph.facebook.com': fbCredentials
      }
    };

    ci.createIdentityPool(params, console.log);[/code] But I get the error saying that the parameter Logins is unexpected :/

Comment: createIdentityPool do it in the UI/ AWS console, I don't think making it via code makes sense if you have one app. If you wanna do it anyway, the key in params is 'SupportedLoginProviders' and not 'login', I think the javascript doc is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

One of the benefits of using API Gateway is that you can automatically [generate SDKs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html) for your API, which easily integrate with Cognito credentials. This saves you from the trouble of implementing SigV4 auth yourself.

Here are a couple of simple examples using Cognito credentials with a generated JavaScript SDK:

1. https://github.com/rpgreen/aws-recipes/blob/master/app/index.html
2. https://github.com/awslabs/api-gateway-secure-pet-store

Cheers,
Ryan

Comment: The generated code is not very clean and it is a mess to edit. On the other hand if you want to make a js client for your API, you can reverse engineer AWS SDK and you will find that they have a factory for building APIs from json files. the class is called AWS.Model.Api(), that is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan mentioned, the best way to do this is via the API Gateway SDK.  The downside to using this stack is that it becomes harder to integrate with off the shelf front-end tools.  You can no longer make direct request to your REST end-points, you will want to go through the SDK.

You definitely lose some ease of development because you can't just slap something like ngResource on top of your endpoints and call it a day.  You'll have to set up the calls to each of your AWS end points in a service layer yourself.